# How old is "process prioritization"? (i.e. Windows Task Manager Set Process Prioritiy, etc)

Tags: multithreading, process

Is process prioritization a Window's or old linux technology.

It appears Windows 95 did not have Process Prioritization in Task Manager, but Windows 2k did.

I believe Process Priorization = kernel preemption..I've been searching along those lines.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely not a Windows tech. Linux had `nice` since the beginning which was 1992 and it was copied from Unix which was written in 1969 and Unix is a super simplified OS based on ideas form the MULTICS project which certainly had them and was started in 1965.

Process priority is not directly related to preemptive multitasking. Indeed, some early preemptive kernels implemented fixed priority. And kernel preemption has been known by another name since before the idea of kernels was invented: it's called interrupts. (Modern kernel preemption by real-time OS is called that to separate userland interrupts from traditional hardware interrupts).

One of the most dramatic examples of the use of process prioritization happened on the Apollo 11 mission that landed Neil Armstrong on the moon. During landing, a misconfigured hardware started running tasks on the flight control computer. This overloaded the CPU. Fortunately the additional tasks were low priority and so was delayed or aborted by the OS. This gave just enough processing time to the critical maneuvering tasks so that the crew had enough control of the craft to land safely. The Apollo flight control computers did not use preemptive multasking. They used cooperative multasking coupled with a real time watchdog monitor (think of it as a very basic, primitive kernel). Neil Armstrong landed in 1969 and the Apollo program started in 1961.

I have a feeling that the idea is older than the 60s and probably originated at IBM (the majority of ideas in computing are, though others were often the first to popularize them).

---

### Additional answer:

OK, it turns out that MULTICS was one of the first piece of software ever written as an OS. The project started as a result of an early experimental OS at MIT called CTTS (CompaTible Time-sharing System). Back then multitasking was known as timesharing. Over time these two words evolved to mean different aspects of running multiple processes simultaneously.

So the idea of process priority was invented at around the same time as the idea of processes which started in the late 50s or early 60s. Most of the research into this area at that time took place at MIT.

Answer (score 1):

Preemptive multitasking has been around quite a while.  At least a decade before Win/95 on home computers, longer on big iron.  Amiga OS (mid-80s), Sinclair QDOS (about the same time frame) are a couple examples of consumer OS platforms with it.  It's been in UNIX, VMS, etc. since 'forever' basically.  Process priority levels go back very far, although I don't know which OS had them first.